# default backend - 404 without www ( ingress )

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
 annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  ingress.bluemix.net/rewrite-path: "serviceName=nginx rewrite=/"
 name: nginx-ingress 
 namespace: 'default'  
spec:
 rules:
 - host: www.domain.com
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /*
       backend:
         serviceName: nginx
         servicePort: 80
```

Here I have some ingress config `yaml` file. When I apply it all working correctly but only when you go by path `www.domain.com` , when I try to use `domain.com` , it doesn't work and return me

> default backend - 404

What should I do ? Add one more host to the rules:

```
 - host: domain.com
   http:
     paths:
     - path: /*
       backend:
         serviceName: nginx
         servicePort: 80
```

Like this or I can use better solving of this problem ?

Answer (score 5):

add an ingress alias annotation to the `annotations` block:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias:  domain.com
```

Comment: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: domain.com , I've added this , but i see The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Answer (score 4):

You can set another host rule for the `domain.com`. However, this is more suitable if you want different path rules for it. To use the same rules, it's better to set the [`server-alias`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-alias) annotation:

> Allows the definition of one or more aliases in the server definition
>   of the NGINX configuration using the annotation
>   `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: "<alias 1>,<alias 2>"`. This
>   will create a server with the same configuration, but adding new
>   values to the `server_name` directive.

Use this:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias:  domain.com`

Remember that you can configure the [`from-to-www-redirect`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#redirect-fromto-www) annotation too:

> In some scenarios is required to redirect from `www.domain.com` to
>   `domain.com` or vice versa. To enable this feature use the annotation
>   `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"`

Comment: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-alias: domain.com , I've added this , but i see The requested URL / was not found on this server , also tried redirect true - the same . And one more question , when I do ( kubectl apply -f ingress.yaml ) , how much time should I wait to know than new config already working ? because I see that is isn't work exactly after setting new yaml file config

Comment: The Nginx controller watches the Ingress resource and triggers a configuration reload when it detects changes. Generally, it is almost instant...you can check the logs from the Nginx Controller pod to know if the change was catch and applied.

Comment: I've checked GCP yaml file and see changes which I've applied

Comment: But there is the same issue

Comment: Should I only add one this line or do some additional changes ?

Comment: Are you using the [Kubernetes Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) image or other implementation for your controller? I see both `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` and  `ingress.bluemix.net` on your configuration...

Comment: I've added this 2 lines because I've tried to fix issue with 404 error on my assets files ( like js bandle ) , etc, I've found this like solving of my problem . I wasn't added it deliberately

Comment: `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io` annotations are supported when using the [Kubernetes Nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) image for your controller. You need to check if you are using it. If using the Kubernetes image, you should also check if the controller is using the [`--annotations-prefix`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/cli-arguments.md) flag to change the prefix of the annotations.

Comment: I understood . I use core kubernetes ingress and it don't support command which you have been written, this is the reason why it doesn't work on my side

Answer (score 0):

Not sure our solution applies in you case.
We also faced similar issue(not exact), we didn't want to change the deployed ingress(i.e. can't add server-alias)
So we some how made sure that all host address typed in browser/request translates to what is configured in ingress.

In this example, we would have created entry in local /etc/hosts

www.domain.com